# Insert multiple rows into sdf file database with one insert

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-ce, sql-insert, sdf

I have function to insert into my SQL Server CE database.

```
private void update_database(string SQL_string)
{
        DBconnection.Open();
        SqlCeCommand SQL_querry = DBconnection.CreateCommand();
        SQL_querry.CommandText = SQL_string;
        SQL_querry.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DBconnection.Close();
}
```

I'm passing to it `SQL` string calling

```
SQL_string = @"insert into Cities(City, destination, distance) values('liege','aberdeen','386'), ('liege','kassel','348');";
update_database(SQL_string);
```

and it throws an exception:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 81,Token in error = , ]"

which clearly states, that problem is with comma after first set of values...
What is the most confusing for me is that when passing this sql_string:

```
SQL_string = @"insert into Cities(City, destination, distance) values('liege','aberdeen','386');";
```

it works without any problem.

Does `SqlCeCommand` accept multirow insertions? What am I missing here?

Comment: From a google search, SQL CE does not support this insert syntax.  Have you tried individual insert statements?

Comment: I was searching google for it, but propably could not ask the correct question to find answer. Yes, I've tried multiple individual inserts - it works well. I just thougth I can do it in one insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't imagine why something like the following wouldn't work.  (I separated the lines for ease of readability).

```
var SQL_string = "insert into Cities(City, destination, distance)";
SQL_string += " SELECT 'liege', 'aberdeen', '386'";
SQL_string += " UNION";
SQL_string += " SELECT 'liege', 'kassel', '348'";
update_database(SQL_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in SQL Server Compact Edition.  However you should be able to either execute individual insert statements, or insert multiple rows from a derived table.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174633

```
INSERT INTO Cities(City, destination, distance)
SELECT s.City, s.Destination, s.distance
FROM (
    SELECT 'liege' AS CITY, 'aberdeen' AS DESTINATION, '386' AS DISTANCE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'liege' AS CITY, 'kassel' AS DESTINATION, '348' AS DISTANCE
) s
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this;

```
SQL_string = @"insert into Cities(City, destination, distance) values('liege','aberdeen','386');";
SQL_string += @"insert into Cities(City, destination, distance) values('liege','kassel','348');";
update_database(SQL_string);
```

Tiny note: If this is a homework or a simple project this may suffice but for anything bigger I recommend using a framework to deal with DB. For example; this code suspiciously looks vulnerable to SQL Injection :)

Comment: This acctually does not answer my question. I have an answer in comment right now. It does not support. I've tried multiple single inserts and it worked. That would be internal database for program without any posibilites for user to access it. If end user will screew  database, then he will have problems with his offline program, not me ;)